# STI: user has multiple child class ids.( I want the user has only one of the child class id)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sti

I'm trying to use STI because I want to use single sign-in page for a device. I want to assign either `teacher_id` or `student_id` to a `user`, but it turned out that all the `user` has both. How can I fix this problem? Below are the models and the migration.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  DEFAULT_ROLE = 'Student'
  after_create :set_role
  attr_accessible ..., :role
  has_one :role
  ...
  private
    def set_role
      self.role ||= Role.find_by_name(DEFAULT_ROLE)
    end
  ...
end


class Student < User
  has_many :bookings
end

Class Teacher < User
  has_many :bookings
end

class Role < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :name, :presence => true
  belongs_to :user
end

Class Booking < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :student_id, :teacher_id
  belongs_to :teacher, :class_name => 'Teacher'
  belongs_to :student, :class_name => 'Student'
  ...

class CreateBookings < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :bookings do |t|
      t.integer :student_id
      t.integer :teacher_id
      t.date :booking_date
      t.time :booking_time

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Separate authorization from Student/Teacher and you shouldn't need STI anymore.

Comment: Do you mean deleting User table and create Teacher and Student table separately?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to separate the "role" part of User into a separate object and then allow users to have multiple roles. Sometimes these are called "profiles" as they really refer to a way of presenting the user.

You can then use the user model as a proxy for accessing these things where you'd test for the presence of the profile:

```
if (user.teacher)
  # ...
else
  flash[:notice] = "You must be a teacher to perform this operation."
end
```

Comment: Thank for your advice. Do you mean I should use polymorphic association?